# SecurityContextPersistenceFilter clears SecurityContextHolder after filter chain is finished

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-filter

I am currently studying Spring Security Fundamentals. I was reading documentation and source code as I like to get as much detailed information about what happens under the hood as possible. Everything is somewhat understandable except one thing:

`SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` Filter class is first filter of Spring Security according to [this page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#filter-ordering) The implementation of this class's `doFilter()` method looks like this:

```
private void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (request.getAttribute("__spring_security_scpf_applied") != null) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        request.setAttribute("__spring_security_scpf_applied", Boolean.TRUE);
        if (this.forceEagerSessionCreation) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled() && session.isNew()) {
                this.logger.debug(LogMessage.format("Created session %s eagerly", session.getId()));
            }
        }

        HttpRequestResponseHolder holder = new HttpRequestResponseHolder(request, response);
        SecurityContext contextBeforeChainExecution = this.repo.loadContext(holder);
        boolean var10 = false;

        try {
            var10 = true;
            SecurityContextHolder.setContext(contextBeforeChainExecution);
            if (contextBeforeChainExecution.getAuthentication() == null) {
                this.logger.debug("Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext");
            } else if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                this.logger.debug(LogMessage.format("Set SecurityContextHolder to %s", contextBeforeChainExecution));
            }

            chain.doFilter(holder.getRequest(), holder.getResponse());
            var10 = false;
        } finally {
            if (var10) {
                SecurityContext contextAfterChainExecution = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
                this.repo.saveContext(contextAfterChainExecution, holder.getRequest(), holder.getResponse());
                request.removeAttribute("__spring_security_scpf_applied");
                this.logger.debug("Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request");
            }
        }

        SecurityContext contextAfterChainExecution = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        this.repo.saveContext(contextAfterChainExecution, holder.getRequest(), holder.getResponse());
        request.removeAttribute("__spring_security_scpf_applied");
        this.logger.debug("Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request");
    }
}
```

The question I have is this: obviously, after filter chain has done its job, `SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()` method is called either in finally block or at the end of the method. However I know that, I can still access SecurityContext object with `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` in my controller and service layer. How is it possible if above code clears SecurityContextHolder? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the documentation you are referring to is version 4.1.2 of spring security, which was released 21 december 2016. Spring security is currently on 5.6.1 and [the filter list looks a lot different in the current documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-security-filters).

Then the answer to your question in the above code is, **because of this line**

```
this.repo.saveContext(contextAfterChainExecution, holder.getRequest(), holder.getResponse());
```

The `SecurityContextHolder` is a singleton, so the `SecurityContext` is fetched (which will create a copy) then it is cleared in the `singleton` and lastly `this.repo.save` saves the context for the next time.

How this is saved, is different, per default believe it uses HttpSession (which means you will get a session cookie), which is implemented in Spring in the [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java), but you can set up a separate database for it to be persistently saved if you'd like it, so that it still remains after restarts etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought that  SecurityContextHolder.clearContext() was called in the filter before request got to controller methods. Apparently request goes through filterchain, calls endpoint method (at that point SecurityContextHolder still contains SecurityContext) and when method is done, request returns to SecurityContextPersistenceFilter and SecurityContext is saved in session and cleared from SecurityContextHolder. I always thought that filters are called before controller methods and that's it, request isn't returned back. That is kind of strange to be honest.

Comment: ah no, you see thats why there is always a `request` AND a `response` object in each do filter. As you see `chain.doFilter` passes the the request to the next filter in the chain but you have to remember that the `chain.doFilter` calls the next then the next, then the controller etc but eventually they all will return, and we will continue the code after the doFilter.

Comment: so basically we pass down 2 objects, one `request` object that is filled with information that we take information from, and one "empty" `response` that will get filled as we go deeper and deeper down

Comment: Yes now I understand. Again huge thanks for clarification.

Comment: please accept the answer if you felt it helped you